# nested "async with" using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I would like to create a scheduler class that uses aiohttp to make API calls. I tried this:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class MySession:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            self.session = session
            return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.session:
            await self.session.close()

async def method1():
    async with MySession() as s:
        async with s.session.get("https://www.google.com") as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                print("successful call!")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(method1())
loop.close()
```

but this just results in an error: `RuntimeError: Session is closed`.

A second approach for the `__aenter__` function:

```
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        return self
```

works well. Is this a good construct? It doesn't adhere to examples of how to use aiohttp. Also wondering why the first approach isn't working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `with` inside a function and have the context manager remain open, no. The `with with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:` block exits as soon as you use `return` to exit the `__aenter__` coroutine!

For the specific case, entering a `aiohttp.ClientSession()` context manager [does nothing but return `self`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/690a3d4053e416d8c0c534ba1e330326074ea664/aiohttp/client.py#L861-L862). So for *that type*, just creating the instance and storing it in `self.session`, and awaiting on `self.session.close()` suffices here, yes.

The *general* pattern for a nested asynchronous context manager is to await the `__aenter__` and `__aexit__` methods of a nested async context manager from your own such methods (and perhaps pass along the exception information):

```
class MySession:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        await self.session.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.session:
            return await self.session.__aexit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

Technically speaking, you should first assure that there is an actual `__aexit__` attribute before entering a nested context manager:

```
class MySession:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None
        self._session_aexit = None

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self._session_aexit = type(self.session).__aexit__
        await self.session.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.session:
            return await self._session_aexit.__aexit__(
                self.session, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

See the [official PEP that added the concept](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with).

Comment: To be 100% correct I think you should use the value returned by aenter: `self.session = await self.session.__aenter__()` Most of the context managers just `return self` in aenter but that doesn't have to be always the case.

Comment: @Messa: that depends on your use-cases for your wrapper and the wrapped context manager, though. If the wrapped context manager returns `self`, you want your wrapper to replace it and so `return self` is the correct choice, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage that dependency externally:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class MySession:

    def __init__(self, client_session):
        self.session = client_session

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass

async def method1():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client_session:
        async with MySession(client_session) as s:
            async with s.session.get("https://www.google.com") as resp:
                if resp.status == 200:
                    print("successful call!")

asyncio.run(method1())
```

When that `async with` chain becomes too ridiculous you can use [`AsyncExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.AsyncExitStack):

```
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack

async def method1():
    async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
        client_session = await stack.enter_async_context(aiohttp.ClientSession())
        s = await stack.enter_async_context(MySession(client_session))
        async with s.session.get("https://www.google.com") as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                print("successful call!")
```